# QT NOOB: Add action handler for multiple objects of same type

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a simple QT application with 10 radio buttons with names radio_1 through radio_10. It is a ui called Selector, and is part of a class called TimeSelector

In my header file for this design, i have this:

```
//! [1]
class TimeSelector : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TimeSelector(QWidget *parent = 0);

private slots:
    //void on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(int value);
    //void on_inputSpinBox2_valueChanged(int value);

private:
    Ui::Selector ui;
};
//! [1]
```

the commented out void_on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(int value) is from the tutorial for the simple calculator. I know i can do:

```
void on_radio_1_valueChanged(int value);
```

but I would need 10 functions. I want to be able to make one function that works for everything, and lets me pass in maybe a name of the radio button that called it, or a reference to the radio button so i can work with it and determine who it was.

I am very new to QT but this seems like it should be very basic and doable, thanks.

Comment: Be aware that `QSpinBox` and `QRadioButton` do not have the same signals and methods. Most notably, there is no `valueChanged(int)` signal on `QRadioButton` but there is a `toggled(bool)` signal that is emitted when the `QRadioButton` checked state changes.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a unique slot and obtain the object that emitted the signal with the `QObject::sender()` method. The following code presents an example of such slot:

```
public slots:
  void onRadioToggled(bool checked)
  {
    QRadioButton *radio = qobject_cast< QRadioButton* >(QObject::sender());
    // radio is the object that emitted the triggered signal
    // if the slot hasn't been triggered by a QRadioButton, radio would be NULL
    if (radio) {
      qDebug() << radio->objectName() << " is set to " << checked << ".";
    }
  }
```

Note that `radio->objectName()` will not give you a good result unless you define it explicitly somewhere.

Now, you can connect the `toggled(bool checked)` signal of every `QRadioButton` to the `onRadioToggled` slot. Note that `QRadioButton` does not have any `valueChanged` signal so your code cannot actually work.

```
connect(radio_1, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), SLOT(onRadioToggled(bool)));
connect(radio_2, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), SLOT(onRadioToggled(bool)));
...
connect(radio_10, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), SLOT(onRadioToggled(bool)));
```

Comment: I figured out in the designer you can select buttons, right click and assign them to a button group. But IMO your approach is better because it can be applied to other controls too, like sliders and edit boxes too.

Answer (score 1):

In the radiobutton case, add the buttons to a QButtonGroup.
Similar functionality offers QSignalMapper.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create your own radio button class that inherits from QRadioButton and create a signal. This signal can have all the parameters you want.

```
void CheckWithReference(YourRadioButtonClass* rb);
```

or

```
void CheckWithReference(QString RadioButtonName);
```

or anything you would like to have.

Then create a slot in your `TimeSelector` class with the same set of parameters you will connect to all signals.

Comment: While this approach would work, I don't recommend it for a Qt beginner.